# Using Bash Variables in Qt4

Tags: c++, bash, shell, variables, qt4

I want to read some variables from a .sh file and pass them to an array (maybe better a vector because i won't know the lengh?). The variables aren't environment ones, with other words, i'll set them per hand.
These variables will be global used by the way.

After this I use them to set a command-, icon- and a namelist for a QListWidget.
I i select an item and click a button it executes the command and displays the result in an QTextEdit.

[--> You can see the code here. <--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659604/qlistwidget-item-add-icon-from-array)

How can i achieve this and is there a better solution?

---

EDIT:

Im sorry, but english isn't my native language so its hard to explain ...

At first the files which are:
Dialog.h, Dialog.cpp and Dialog.ui

Then the Files which contains the function:
Query.h and Query.cpp

At least the Script wich i call variables.sh for example.
It contains something like this:

```
CmdList=("kcmshell4 --list|grep -q kcm_grub2",
         "kcmshell4 --list|grep -q kcm_networkmanagement",
         "which pastebunz",
         "[ -z $ink3_ver ]")

NameList=("kcm_grub2",
          "kcm_networkmanagement",
          "pastebunz",
          "Shellmenu")

IconList=(":/icons/icons/GNU.png",
          ":/icons/icons/networkmanager.png",
          ":/icons/icons/edit-paste.png",
          ":/icons/icons/menu.png")
```

I dont know the length or content of these. So i should use QVector right?

The Query function is called via a button from the Dialog Ui.

Now i must read the variables from variables.h (this should be done at programstart ...).

```
for (int i = 0; i < ${#$cmdList[*]}; i++) // where '${#$cmdList[*]}' represents the
{ some magical stuff; }                  //legth or the $CmdList array written in bash ...
```

Then i must use some loop in my function in Query.cpp like

```
QVector<QString> vCmdList;
for (int i = 0; i < vCmdList.size(); i++)
{
    vCmdList[i] = CmdList[i];
}
```

I hope its clearer now because i have no idea how to explain it more precicely.

Thanks for your patience ^^

Comment: Can you provide a small example of what you have and what you expect ?

Comment: If you click an the link then you can see the function in which i need the variables/arrays.

I wan't so change the c++/Qt arrays on top of the function to something which loads the basharrays and fills the c++ arrays with their content. I have only the function shown in the link. So this is more a theoretical question ...

I can write a pseydo code if that helps?

Comment: Instead of linking to that question, why don't you copy the relevant parts? Because right now I don't think it's clear which parts are (and aren't) relevant.

Comment: If I understand well, you'd like to edit a file and feed it with bash variables at some places ?

Comment: No. The file and $variables are already there. I want to read them in c++/Qt4 to use their content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use `QSettings` and an .ini file to store your commands than bash arrays.

For example:

```
[kcm_grub2]
command=kcmshell4 --list|grep -q kcm_grub2
icon=:/icons/icons/GNU.png

[kcm_networkmanagement]
command=kcmshell4 --list|grep -q kcm_networkmanagement
icon=:/icons/icons/networkmanager.png
...
```

With `QSettings::childGroups()`, you'll be able to iterate over all the command names to then read the command and the icon path for each name.

Comment: This works well. Never thought of that simple solution -.-

Thanks a lot! Now i try to get my loop done.

Comment: This solves my problem. Only thing whats left is to write some kind of wrapper for the shellstuff. Thanks!